# readfile returns a corrupt zip download

Tags: php, phalcon

I have the following code in my Phalcon application.

```
public function downloadAction($key = NULL) {
    if ($key == NULL) {
        return $this->respondDownloadFailed();
    }

    $url = Urls::findFirst("token = '".$key."'");

    if ($url) {
        $path = $url->getUrl();

        $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        header("Content-type: application/".$ext); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$key.".".$ext);
        header("Content-length: " . filesize($path));
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
        header("Expires: 0"); 

        ob_clean();
        flush();

        readfile($path);
        unlink($path);
        die;
    }

    return $this->respondDownloadFailed();
}
```

Now, when the `.zip` is created on the server I can open and unzip it. However, when I download it through the code above, I get a zip file which then unarchives to a `.cpgz` file. When unarchiving that one, I get a `.zip` again. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Open the ZIP file in a text editor. I bet you have a PHP error message somewhere in the middle of the file (maybe caused by `unlink()`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I did just that and there's no error. The strange part is that when I download it, it works. But when a friend downloads it, it's corrupt.

Comment: You mean there's no error in your friend's downloaded file, don't you?